# Android: AsyncTask for web service not cancelling in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I have a fragment in which i execute `AsyncTask` to fetch json response from web service.

I want to cancel the `AsyncTask` of the fragment, `cancel` function is called for the asynctask but its not working:

```
@Override
public void onDetach() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDetach();

    if(wsClient != null && wsClient.getStatus() == Status.RUNNING && !wsClient.isCancelled())
        wsClient.cancel(true);

}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStop();
    if(wsClient != null && wsClient.getStatus() == Status.RUNNING && !wsClient.isCancelled())
        wsClient.cancel(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check isCancelled() yourself. Calling cancel() will not interrupt your asyncTask.

> A task can be cancelled at any time by invoking cancel(boolean).
>   Invoking this method will cause subsequent calls to isCancelled() to
>   return true. After invoking this method, onCancelled(Object), instead
>   of onPostExecute(Object) will be invoked after
>   doInBackground(Object[]) returns. To ensure that a task is cancelled
>   as quickly as possible, you should always check the return value of
>   isCancelled() periodically from doInBackground(Object[]), if possible
>   (inside a loop for instance.)

see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 0):

Try run cancel() function in onPause method .  Good luck.